# Log4j2 JSONLayout not appending closing (]) square bracket

Tags: java, log4j

Here is my `log4j2.xml` config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="OFF">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="JsonFile" fileName="logs/myLog.log" immediateFlush="true" append="false">
            <JSONLayout complete="true" charset="UTF-8" compact="false" eventEol="false" properties="true"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="JsonFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The output looks as follows:

```
[
{
  "timeMillis" : 1503303149998,
  "thread" : "Restlet-343114711",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "my.logger.name",
  "message" : "Import completed successfully",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "contextMap" : {
    "class" : "my.package.Class",
    "method" : "getProgress",
    "user" : "myUser"
  },
  "threadId" : 45,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
```

Which is missing a closing square bracket. How do I configure log4j2 to add the closing tag?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that appender but it looks like the file contains a list of objects that represent individual log entries. As such I'd assume the closing bracket is written when that list is complete, e.g. when a rolling based on size or time happens.

Comment: Thank you very much @Thomas. It only adds the closing bracket when the next roll happens

Comment: I had to replace `RandomAccessFile` with `File`.

Answer (score 0):

For others who might be facing this issue with console appenders, and would like log4j to append the `]` when the execution is finisehd (in case of a CLI for example).

You can stop the appender which will make log4j add the closing `]`

```
// Notice casting from spi.LoggerContext to core.LoggerContext    
LoggerContext logContext = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Map<String, LoggerConfig> map = logContext.getConfiguration().getLoggers();
map.get(LOGGER_NAME).getAppenders().get(APPENDER_NAME).stop();
```

If you appender is attached to the root logger, use an empty string `""` for the the variable `LOGGER_NAME`

Comment: Log4j installs a [shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)), which stops the appenders automatically. There is no need to do it manually, unless you have a web app (the `javax.servlet.Servlet` class is present), then the shutdown hook is disabled.

Comment: it wasn't working in my case, maybe because of non-zero exit code?