# Logging in a json file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

my application runs with angular 7 and spring boot 2. 
I need to store some data in a json file every time a user interacts with the application (click on some buttons or links). The json should look like this (just an example) :

```
[
 "event": {

   userid : 1
   ipAddress : x.x.x.x
   lastConnectionDateTime : ...,
   action : "click on link 1"
 },
 "event": {

   userid : 2
   ipAddress : y.y.y.y
   lastConnectionDateTime : ...,
   action : "click on button THE_BUTTON" 
 },
 ...
]
```

I see 2 options :

- doing it manually with an angular interceptor that calls a webservice asynchronously. The webservice would then call an Async spring service that appends the data in the json file.
  With this solution i will have to wipe myself data older than a week, which feels like recreating the wheel.
- using logging libraries like log4j2 or logback.
  In log4j2 there is JsonLayout that could help me do this with "loggerFields" containing a List of "KeyValuePairs" to put custom fields in my json but i have 3 problems with this :

  - how to put my own values in  that are not the pre-defined %c, %t...etc. Maybe something like this : Logger.info("event", "userid", "1", "ipAddress", "x.x.x.x"...etc);  ?
  - using the method seems to produces a json with a "message" field that contains my custom values. how to put them in the root level of my event objects like in the example i gave above ?
  - i'm afraid this will conflict with my default spring boot logger configuration cause i also need to use the default logging system that writes logs in a normal log file. Can i cread a Logger.someOtherLevelThanInfoDebugErrorWarn("",""); ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can create a specific logger for the java class which needs to write to json and use json specific appender with this logger. Rest of the logging will continue as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding this part of your question:

> - using logging libraries like log4j2 or logback. In log4j2 there is JsonLayout that could help me do this with "loggerFields" containing a
>     List of "KeyValuePairs" to put custom fields in my json but i have 3
>     problems with this :
>
>   - how to put my own values in  that are not the pre-defined %c, %t...etc. Maybe something like this :
>       Logger.info("event", "userid", "1", "ipAddress", "x.x.x.x"...etc);  ?

I think in this bullet point you're asking about how you would inject the values for your dynamic variables into the `JsonLayout`'s `KeyValuePair` element. The answer is that you would use a [lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) just like in the example at the end of the [JsonLayout documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout) - something like `<KeyValuePair key="additionalField2" value="$${ctx:key}"/>`

> - using the method seems to produces a json with a "message" field that contains my custom values. how to put them in the root level of
>     my event objects like in the example i gave above ?

I refer you back to the above - if you use a [lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) the data will be placed under its own key within the generated JSON.

> - i'm afraid this will conflict with my default spring boot logger configuration cause i also need to use the default logging system that
>     writes logs in a normal log file. Can i cread a
>     Logger.someOtherLevelThanInfoDebugErrorWarn("",""); ?

There are several ways you could handle separating your other log events from the JSON events. I suggest you look at using [markers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html) together with the [MarkerFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter) **or** creating a logger config with a special name (I suggest carefully reading the [architecture page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html) of the log4j2 manual to understand how logger names work). For example if you were to create a logger config with a special name you might do something like this:

```
private static final Logger JSON_EVENT_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("JSON_EVENT_LOGGER");
```

This would be defined in your configuration like this (assuming XML config):

```
<Logger name="JSON_EVENT_LOGGER" additivity="false">
    ...
</Logger>
```

I recommend you read about the [additivity attribute](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity) so that you have a good understanding of why it is set to false here. Basically you do not want these json log events going to any parent loggers' appenders.

---

Here is a very simple example that uses the second approach of creating a logger config with a special name:

First a java class to generate some log events:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;


public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static final Logger JSON_EVENT_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("JSON_EVENT_LOGGER");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadContext.put("userid", "1");
        ThreadContext.put("ipAddress", "127.0.0.1");
        ThreadContext.put("lastConnectionDateTime", "...timestamp...");
        ThreadContext.put("action", "click link 1");
        JSON_EVENT_LOGGER.info("A JSON message uses the special logger");

        log.info("A non-json message uses the normal logger");
    }
}
```

Now a log4j2.xml config file defining the loggers and appenders:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <Console name="ConsoleJSON" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonLayout compact="false" eventEol="true" stacktraceAsString="true">
                <KeyValuePair key="userid" value="$${ctx:userid}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="ipAddress" value="$${ctx:ipAddress}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="lastConnectionDateTime" value="$${ctx:lastConnectionDateTime}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="action" value="$${ctx:action}"/>
            </JsonLayout>
        </Console>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="JSON_EVENT_LOGGER" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <Appenderref ref="ConsoleJSON"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When the java class is executed the following logs are generated in the console:

```
{
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "JSON_EVENT_LOGGER",
  "message" : "A JSON message uses the special logger",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "instant" : {
    "epochSecond" : 1576215690,
    "nanoOfSecond" : 541000000
  },
  "threadId" : 1,
  "threadPriority" : 5,
  "userid" : "1",
  "ipAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
  "lastConnectionDateTime" : "...timestamp...",
  "action" : "click link 1"
}
23:41:30.653 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass - A non-json message uses the normal logger
```

---

Here is a very simple example of how to use a `Marker` and the `MarkerFilter` to achieve a similar result.

First the java class:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.MarkerManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class SomeClass2 {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static final Marker JSON_EVENT = MarkerManager.getMarker("JSON_EVENT");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadContext.put("userid", "1");
        ThreadContext.put("ipAddress", "127.0.0.1");
        ThreadContext.put("lastConnectionDateTime", "...timestamp...");
        ThreadContext.put("action", "click link 1");
        log.info(JSON_EVENT, "A JSON message uses the special logger");

        log.info("A non-json message uses the normal logger");
    }
}
```

Notice the differences here - there is only 1 logger object used for both types of messages and one call to the logger includes the `Marker` to indicate that it is a JSON event.

Next, the log4j2.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <MarkerFilter marker="JSON_EVENT" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <Console name="ConsoleJSON" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <MarkerFilter marker="JSON_EVENT" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <JsonLayout compact="false" eventEol="true" stacktraceAsString="true">
                <KeyValuePair key="userid" value="$${ctx:userid}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="ipAddress" value="$${ctx:ipAddress}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="lastConnectionDateTime" value="$${ctx:lastConnectionDateTime}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="action" value="$${ctx:action}"/>
            </JsonLayout>
        </Console>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <Appenderref ref="ConsoleJSON"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Again, notice the differences here - there are 2 appenders but only a single logger configuration (`Root`). The Root logger specifies both appenders and then the appenders are responsible for filtering events using the `MarkerFilter`.

Lastly, the resulting output from running the java code:

```
{
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "example.SomeClass2",
  "marker" : {
    "name" : "JSON_EVENT"
  },
  "message" : "A JSON message uses the special logger",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "instant" : {
    "epochSecond" : 1576275417,
    "nanoOfSecond" : 684000000
  },
  "threadId" : 1,
  "threadPriority" : 5,
  "userid" : "1",
  "ipAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
  "lastConnectionDateTime" : "...timestamp...",
  "action" : "click link 1"
}
16:16:57.756 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass2 - A non-json message uses the normal logger
```

---

Note: I used log4j2 version 2.11.1, if you use a newer version you may see different results. When I tried these same examples with 2.12.1 the JSON output was very different.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer. I think this will help me achieve everything I need :) and thank you for taking the time of making sample codes.

Comment: @batmaniac you're very welcome and I'm glad this was helpful. I had some time to add a second example using the `Marker` and `MarkerFilter` so make sure you take a look at that as well.

Comment: Is the ThreadContext.put() method going to be thread safe ? If two web requests use the same singleton bean that calls the ThreadContext.put method blocs at the same time is it going to mix the userid of a user with the action of another user ? or do i need to do this in a request scope bean ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, see [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) for details.

Comment: It works fine !
however there are two drawbacks with this solution :
- the ending "]" is not present. It seems like it's added when the rolling is done (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792298/log4j2-jsonlayout-not-appending-closing-square-bracket)
This is very annoying cause my json log is meant to be valid cause it's read by another tool which is splunk. I didn't find a way to put a closing "]" yet.
- second drawback : when i restart my server, the comma "," that separates my elements is not appended before adding the first json element which results in an invalid json format too.

Comment: Thank you very much from me. Spent many hours trying to get a solution. Log4j2 and Splunk documentation is respectively, woeful and inadequate. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to D.B.'s answer, which is quite good, you could also using a custom Message object such as:

```
public class EventMessage extends MapMessage {
    private static final String USERID = "userId";
    private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "ipAddress";
    private static final String DATE_TIME = "lastConnectionDateTime";
    private static final String ACTION = "action";

    public EventMessage(String userid, String ipAddress, String dateTime, String action) {
         this.put(USERID, userid);
         this.put(IP_ADDRESS, ipAddress);
         this.put(DATE_TIME, dateTime);
         this.put(ACTION, action);
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedMessage() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        asJson(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Your application would then do:

```
log.info(JSON_EVENT, new EventMessage("jdoe", "127.0.0.1", lastConnectTime, action));
```

at this point your events would already be formatted as JSON. Now all you need is an appender to log the events with the opening and closing array brackets and to place a comma between events. Unfortunately, none of the standard Appenders will do that in a way that would cause the events to look like what you show above. To accomplish that you would need to create a custom Layout such as:

```
@Plugin((name = "EventLayout", category = Node.CATEGORY, elementType = Layout.ELEMENT_TYPE, printObject = true)
public class EventLayout extends AbstractStringLayout {
    private static final Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    private final AtomicBoolean firstFlag = new AtomicBoolean();

    private EventLayout(final Charset aCharset, final byte[] header, final byte[] footer) {
        super(charset, "[\n".getBytes(charset), "\n]".getBytes(charset));
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getHeader() {
        firstFlag.set(true);
        return super.getHeader();
    }

    @Override byte[] getFooter() {
        firstFlag.set(false);
        return super.getFooter();
    }

    @Override
    public String toSerializable(final LogEvent event) {
        final StringBuilder sb = getStringBuilder();
        if (!firstFlag.compareAndSet(true, false) {
            sb.append(",\n");
        }
        sb.append(event.getFormattedMessage();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Then route the message based on the Marker as shown in D.B.'s answer. The JSON the above will produce:

```
[
{ "userid": "1", "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1", "lastConnectionDateTime": "....", "action": "click on link 1"},
{ "userid": "2", "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1", "lastConnectionDateTime": "....", "action": "click on button THE_BUTTON"}
]
```

Note that this differs from what you asked for but your array syntax wasn't correct. I should point out that I didn't test the code above so it may contain errors.

I should also point out that this looks like you are attempting to perform audit logging. You might want to consider looking at [Log4j-Audit](http://logging.apache.org/log4j-audit/latest/) if that is indeed what you want to do

Comment: I'll try the EventMessage and check the log4j-audit ! Thank you very much